# use only required tables for conversation in php-telegram-bot

Tags: php, laravel, telegram, telegram-bot

I installed [php-telegram-bot](https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core) in **laravel 5.5**. and there I used default users table that laravel is provided to Auth and login operations.

In the other hand to register users that comes from telegram bot, we know that should use `conversations` feature to get some user information like **first_name** , **last_name** , ... .

To use conversation we should enable MySQL feature in your package; and in this case that package offers that run [structure.sql](https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core/blob/master/structure.sql) file that included many tables that I do not need.

I just need those tables for **conversation**. Any other tables like `inline_query` ,`callback_query`,`edited_message` is not useful in this case.

Now I want to know is possible to use required tables to conversation only? and what are them? In the other words *Why do we need to use an unused table?*

Comment: Don't just ask for tutorial here, it can easy to do via programming

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to know is possible to use required tables to conversation only? And what are them? In the other words: Why do we need to use an unused table?

The answer to your question depends

1. highly on your requirements
2. on the implementation of the said package (which I don't know)

As this said only you can give answers to this, because nobody than you knows your requirements.

You or one of your engineers needs to analyse the code of the lib to be able to say which tables really needed to fit your requirements and if its safe not creating all tables from the provided SQL file.

This should goes along with the economical question if you want to pay somebody to look through the code for one hour + your time asking this here or just import some tables of which the developers of the lib think they are needed and might stay empty due your requirements.

I am not saying you should blindly import tables from 3rd-parties, only that you should consider the cost/benefit from doing so or not.